# Last summer Modric was one of the first who approached the club to talk about what had happened and what was to come

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

> Last summer Modric was one of the first who approached the club to
>   talk about what had happened and **what was to come**

What does this phrase "what was to come" in the sentence mean?

> what was supposed to happen = what was to come , or not?

Comment: There's a significant difference between *What's to come* (the future, which ***will*** happen), and *What's **supposed** to come* (the ***intended*** future, which ***might not*** happen). Note that idiomatically, most native speakers would say *Modric was one of the first **to approach** the club...* - it's mostly non-native speakers who would be bothered about repetition of the word ***to*** in following ***...to talk about**...*.

Answer (score 1):

'Things that have happened' are events in the past, and 'what is to come' means 'a thing or things that are going to happen in the future'.

Comment: "what was to come" is about past?

Comment: In the past, at the time ('last summer'), 'what was to come' was in the future.